# How i can pass two params Expression inside my method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on an asp.net mvc web application, and i need to pass two params expression as follow:-

```
public RackJoin AllFindDetails(int id, params Expression<Func<Server, object>>[] includeProperties,params Expression<Func<Resource, object>>[] includeProperties2)
        {
```

but the above will raise the following error:-

```
A parameter array must be the last parameter in a formal parameter list
```

Comment: Why do you think that you need that? How do you think that you would call a method if it could have two `params` arrays? How would the compiler know which parameters would belong to which `params` array?

Comment: this is because inside my method i am building a view model which join two models from different context

Comment: Why would you need to use `params` arrays for that?

Comment: to pass the navigation properties that i what to .Include ..

Comment: Why do you think that you need to pass them as a `params` array?

Answer (score 1):

You need to find a different solution. Since `params` just takes every argument given it and stuffs them into an array, two instances of it on the same function don't make sense.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) formalizes this:

> No additional parameters are permitted after the params keyword in a
>   method declaration, and only one params keyword is permitted in a
>   method declaration.

The specification is slightly less specific (Section 1.6.6.1):

> Only the last parameter of a method can be a parameter array, and the type of a parameter array must be a single-dimensional array type.

But only allowing the last parameter to be `params` implies there can only be one, since a second one by definition could not be the last one as well.

Comment: but in my case i need to pass two params becuase i have two model classes from two different contexts,,, and i need to add .Include for them before building a view model ...

Comment: which requires `params` because? Like I said, you don't have a choice, you *have* to find a different solution. I'm not familiar enough with MVC to know exactly what you mean but why not just accept two `IEnumerable`?